# Run CSS animation only once when regenerating a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

```
function draw_flex (){

 html_string = '';
 for( let i=0; i < notes.length; i++) {


html_string += '<div class=" col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-2 ">'

html_string += '<div class="container">';


html_string += '<div class="text">' + notes[i].task + '</div>';
html_string += '<div class="date">' + notes[i].date + '</div>';
html_string += '<div class="time">' + notes[i].time + '</div>';

html_string += '<div class="button" onClick="delete_note_by_key(' + i + ')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>';
html_string += '</div>';
html_string += '</div>';
 }

 html_string += '</div>';
 document.getElementById('my-flex').innerHTML = html_string;

}
```

CSS class Container has an animation:

```
div.container {

background: url('notebg.png') no-repeat;

height: 250px;

animation-duration: 4s;
animation-name: fadeIn;  
}
```

Draw_flex() function runs on form submit, so each time I submit a new Container, the animation runs once again. Ho to make it run only once?

Comment: hi @AntonSusman, have you tried the code below?

Answer (score 0):

you could look for a `div.container` element at the beginning of the function `draw_flex`: if the element exists add a `no-animation` class to the #my-flex container

```
function draw_flex() {

   if (document.querySelectorAll('#my-flex div.container').length > 0) {   
       document.getElementById('my-flex').classList.add('no-animation');
   } 
   ...
}
```

and the CSS becomes

```
div.container {
   background: url('notebg.png') no-repeat;
   height: 250px;
}

#my-flex:not(.no-animation) div.container {
   animation-duration: 4s;
   animation-name: fadeIn;  
}
```

so after the first call to the `draw_flex` function the animation will be disabled.